# Como puedo enviar Excel desde sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Buenas Noches .
Estoy realizando una exportación de un archivo excel a mi correo desde SQL SERVER 2012

por cual si me genera y me llega a mi correo el excel lo malo es que me sale en una sola celda como la imagen que adjunto
Habria una forma en darle formato al excel ?

El codigo que genera y envia al correo es este :

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'IncidenciasQa',
@recipients = 'pflores@qapaq.pe',
@subject = 'Test',
@query = N'exec DBRevisoria.dbo.[Sp_RevCatalogo] 13,2',  
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_width = 150,
@query_result_header= 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'test.xls',
@importance = 'High',
@query_result_no_padding = 1,
@query_result_separator = '     '
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente un Excel "puro" no podrás generar, pero si un archivo de campos separados por comas (`CSV`) que eventualmente podrías llegar a importar en Excel, para hacer esto deberías agregar los siguientes parámetros:

```
@query_result_separator = ',', -- El separador de campos será la ,  
@query_result_no_padding = 1   -- Para quitar el espacio "extra" de cada columna
```

Cualquier cosa revisa la documentación de [`sp_send_dbmail`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql)